# Get an error when setting the key in Bundle.getString()

Tags: android

This is the exemple , I am using Bundle to  it shows me an error indicating that cannot resolve symbol 'donationType'.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, supporterLayoutTwo.class);
                //Create the bundle
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                //Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putString(“donationType”, donationtype);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define what is donationtype is. For example: is it a:

```
int donationtype = 15;
String donationtype = "Donate";
```

Try the following

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, supporterLayoutTwo.class);
                //Create the bundle
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                String donationtype = "donation";
                //Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putString(“donationType”, donationtype);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank u , now I hae set in the other activity                                           
private String donationtype;                                                                               //Get the bundle
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

 //Extract the data…
  donationtype = bundle.getString(“donationType”);                                            and it said cannot resolve symbol donationType.

Comment: Declare String donationtype; first, then assign a value to it. Otherwise donationtype does not exists

Comment: oh I got it I am using  ”  instead of  "